# include markdown with options in Shiny

Tags: shiny, markdown

I want to include my `myMardown.md` document in my Shiny app.
To display a table of content, I use toc options and I also use a css (`myStyle.css`)

`myMarkdown.md` :

```
---
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 2
    css: myStyle.css
---

<div>
###A title using myStyle.css {.bigbaseline}
</div>

# Big chapter 1
## chapter A
## chapter B
# Big chapter 2
## chapter A
```

`myStyle.css`

```
.bigbaseline {
   font-size: 2em;
   color: #134C89;
   text-align: center;
   font-style:italic;
}
```

In RStudio when I preview myMarkdown.md (using `pandoc`) the table of content is displayed and the title using css works fine.

But I'm afraid that when I use includeMarkdown function the **front-matter** of myMarkdown.md document **is not taken into account**. Because I can't see the table of content neither the title with css.

`app.R`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("doc_to_display")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$doc_to_display <- renderUI({
    includeMarkdown("myMarkdown.md")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried also `includeHTML` but in my Shiny app I have several `tabPanel` (I use `navbarPage`) and once I go to the `tabPanel` containing the HTML document I can't switch back to others `tabPanel`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found a solution thanks to the workaround in question [42422771](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422771/including-markdown-tables-in-shiny-app-seems-to-break-css)

This include HTML.
**Toc** options are available, **css** works fine & I can switch from one panel to another one without makes the shiny app freeze.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$iframe(src = './myMarkdown.html', # put myMarkdown.html to /www
              width = '100%', height = '800px', 
              frameborder = 0, scrolling = 'auto'
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! This works perfectly. Indeed a critical piece is to make sure the `myMarkdown.html` file is in the `www/` folder within `app/`